# Updating a python scraper that no longer works due to javascript blocks

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

So I had written a scraper (deployed on a schedule) which worked pretty well until recently when the site (NYTimes) made changes that broke it

Essentially the scraper worked by going to an article URL, and using using xpath to extract the full artcile content which I would pass to an LLM in order to summarize it

Here's the code:

--

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector

url ='https://www.nytimes.com/2024/02/06/us/politics/border-ukraine-israel-aid-congress.html' #works with any nytimes article url

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
    'DNT': '1',  
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',  
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',  
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
# response

sel = Selector(text=response.text)
b = sel.xpath('//section[@class="meteredContent css-1r7ky0e"]')   
art =  b.xpath('.//p[@class="css-at9mc1 evys1bk0"]').extract()  #article body
art2 = '\n '.join(art) #newline   
art2 = html2text.html2text(art2)   #convert from html to human/LLM readable text
print(art2)
#pass to an LLM via api
```

--

Previously, the code above would return the entire article. Now, it returns a partial article because a javascript screen is thrown app asking for human verification before the full article can be rendered

I have two questions:

1. This is a fairly high-frequency call so is there anything clever I can do to get around this limitation without incorporating a heavy stack that involves rendering javascript through a browser for every call, e.g. using hidden API endpoints or incorporating header values that would suggest this call is from a human?
2. If the answer to 1 is No, then what is the simplest, most lightweight library, package and approach to render javascript and scrape it for this type of site? I am running this script on a very lightweight server so I really want to try and NOT bloat the memory/infrastructure requirements needed to run this code

Thanks so much

Comment: What about leaving them alone? According to you, they don't want their articles to be summarized before reading imposing on their readers the effort of proving their identitiy because of the machines they started to fight against? Are the news worth to engage as a soldier into the information war between liars?

Comment: As I can see they provide the option of 0.50 $ per week of unlimited access to their news. With half an hour of work on overcoming the issue you "pay" with the work for one year of unlimited access ... Isn't investment of some money not a better option compared to the investment of time for solving issues because of ongoing changes in the process of the war against the machines?

Comment: FWIW - I actually do have a subscription (for a lot more than the amount above). I wish they allowed API access to their articles with a paid key for subscribers, but unfortunately, they don't

Comment: If you have a subscription how does it come that they ask for human verification? So they you let you pay (maybe you switch to the 0.50 $ plan?), but don't allow non-human access for the account anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://www.nytimes.com/2024/02/06/us/politics/border-ukraine-israel-aid-congress.html"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = re.search(r"window\.__preloadedData = (.*}});", html_text).group(1)
data = data.replace(":undefined", ":null")
data = json.loads(data)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

headline = None
summary = None
content = []

for c in data["initialData"]["data"]["article"]["sprinkledBody"]["content"]:
    match c["__typename"]:
        case "HeaderBasicBlock":
            headline = c["headline"]["content"][0]["text"]
            summary = c["summary"]["content"][0]["text"]
        case "ParagraphBlock":
            t = "".join(cc["text"] for cc in c["content"])
            content.append(t)

print(headline)
print()
print(summary)
print("-" * 80)
print("\n\n".join(content))
```

Prints:

```
With Demise of Border Deal, No Clear Path for Ukraine and Israel Aid in Congress

The House was set to consider an Israel-only aid bill that faced bipartisan resistance and a veto threat from President Biden. The Senate’s broader package with Ukraine aid appeared dead.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The decision by Republicans in Congress to torpedo a bipartisan border deal they demanded has left the fate of aid to Ukraine and Israel in peril, closing off what had been seen as the best remaining avenue on Capitol Hill for approval of critical military aid to American allies.

The political paralysis in the face of pleas from President Biden, lawmakers in both parties and leaders around the world for quick action raised immediate questions about whether Congress would be able to salvage the emergency aid package — and if so, how.

...
```

Comment: My experience from visiting their article was that there was no human user verification there, Hmmm ... May you explain what is the main idea behind your proposal and how does it come that OP experienced an issue?

Comment: > python3.10 -u "NYTarticleAccess.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/o/oOo/O@@/stackoverflow/NYTarticleAccess.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = re.search(r"window\.__preloadedData = (.*}});", html_text).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
> exit status: 256